# What happened to Borland Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have the impression that Delphi isn't very popular anymore. But now at work I had to make some changes to an old Delphi program that we are still using. I used Borland Developer Studio 2006 and it was very pleasant and intuitive to work with, even though I had practically no previous exposure to it. Is Delphi still widely-used and I am simply not aware of it or are there other reasons for its decline?

Comment: One thing to realize: As you say, it's very pleasant and intuitive to work with, and you're not the only one who's noticed that.  Some companies, in fact, consider the productivity that Delphi brings to be a true competitive advantage. They make sure to keep very quiet about using Delphi so their competition doesn't catch on. So what you end up with is *a pretty widely-used language that doesn't have a very high profile.*

Comment: Borland is dead, Delphi is not. I once asked Jeff Duntemann who "Frank Borland" was, thinking he started Borland. Jeff told me that Philippe Kahn created the Frank Borland personna as a marketing gimmick.

Comment: www.isdelphidead.com  ;)

Comment: Funnily enough I always assumed somebody created Philippe Kahn as a marketing gimmick!

Comment: +1 for bringing back many fond memories of Delphi! An amazing product that never quite got the success it deserved (was far superior to anything Microsoft had at the time...). In my view the two big reasons for it being held back were: 1) very poor strategic decisions by Borland management and 2) being squashed by Microsoft

Comment: @Mason, as wierd as that sounds, its true.  A company I worked for did exactly that because it allowed them to compete against larger competitors who used C.  If someone asked, sure, we'd tell them.  But we didnt go out of our way to advertise what we used.

Comment: @Grandmaster, sounds exactly like what Paul Graham did back in the 90'es with Lisp :) http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Delphi is still around and very much alive, but under new ownership.

Borland really lost their way.  They had a really large product line, and the main thing that people were interested in was Delphi, but what the PHBs thought was going to be big was not their development tools, but their Application Lifecycle Management tools.  So they put a lot of resources into developing and promoting that instead of Delphi, and let the development tools branch languish.  I even heard from some former Borland employees at the Delphi Live! conference a few years ago that their sales people were actively discouraged and dis-incentivized (is that a word?) from trying to sell Delphi at all, even to potential clients who expressed interest up-front.

A few years back, things changed.  Borland sold their entire development tools division to Embarcadero Technologies, which up to that point was mostly known for database-related software.  Now their big claim to fame is that they're the guys who make Delphi.  Within a few months of the sale, Borland stock fell below $1/share and they were bought out by a "corporate graveyard" company that basically does nothing but manage licensing fees on existing products. Borland no longer exists.

Embarcadero, though, actually cares about Delphi.  They've put a lot of work and effort into it, and the product quality has improved tremendously in the last few releases.  Despite both the recession **and** Delphi being a commercial-only tool in a perceived "age of open-source development," sales have been really strong and the team's been able to make a lot of progress.

TL;DR: Borland is dead; Delphi is not. It's "Embarcadero Delphi" now, and it's very much alive and kicking.

Comment: Borland was bought by Micro Focus (my former employer). They certainly weren't trying to go by on licensing alone and actively tried to develop the products. The fact that they failed shouldn't be interpreted as corporate graveyard.

Comment: @Christopher? Really? Hmm... that's the first time I've heard anyone say that. Interesting.

Comment: [Cnet News Article](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1001_3-10234650-92.html) They also bought a division from Compuware that had a similar portfolio. The combination did not sell well.

Comment: I've never understood why they didn't offer a version for non-commercial apps **really** cheap, just to attract more users.

Comment: It all started when Borland changed its name to [Inprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inprise#The_Inprise_years.2C_and_name_changes), and then back. Or perhaps before, when [Philippe Kahn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Kahn) left the company. Any way, Borland was founded and lived strong as a company serving software developers, and at one point it decided to shift its attention to corporate mumbo-jumbo. That's when many, like me, felt betrayed, and dangerously trapped in a proprietary technology. Then came Java... I still use Delphi 7 on legacy work.

Comment: Borland management decided that the money was in Application Lifecycle Management instead of in Tools.  It was a question of going after a three-digit number of big Software-and-service contracts, or going after a seven digit number of boxed-software sales. They chose the former, and now where are they?

Comment: @el fuser - how cheap is **really** cheap? There is now a USD$150 starter edition (http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter). Allowing for inflation, this is similar to the original Turbo Pascal pricing

Comment: @Gerry please look under conditions for starter edition, cmon, revenue under $1000 per *YEAR*, is that a joke ? And I live in former eastern european country.

Comment: @Antonio - I know, I don't know what they were thinking, really only allows for hobbyist programmers.

Comment: The revenue limit is pretty dumb, but I *suspect* there's a little bit of Inprise still hanging with them, and purely speculation here, that was some sort of 'trade off' to get those Inprise types to sign off on the lower priced SKU.  That being said, its effectively unenforcable (where its even legal).  Does the maker of a dev tool really want to start suing its *paid* users?  Not gonna happen.

Comment: @Gerry, the original Turbo Pascal price was in a world of expensive software.  Today both the Java and the .NET world has excellent starter versions for free.

Comment: Checked http://www.borland.com/ - I've never heard of any of the products listed.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Actually, I've been around long enough to have heard of all of those.  Ancient; looks more like a dumping ground than anything else.

Comment: @Gerry considering most entry level, trial, evaluation, or starter versions of products don't allow for any revenue.. I'd say $1000 is pretty generous.

Comment: Borland had a sizable offering of languages, tools and applications, but Pascal was their main meal ticket. The problem is that they put all their eggs in the Windows basket when they could have branched out to the Macintosh market. It may have been much smaller, but they could have owned the cross platform development strategy. The fact that Mac development was still done in Pascal made it a no brainer. Had they played their cards right, Java would have been a non-starter. Sorry, but Java has nothing on Object Pascal.

Answer (score 12):

Newer versions (notably XE) are far more better than 2006, that was pretty buggy version. And Delphi usage is definitly declining and IMO only reason is price. Delphi is *very* expensive and there is no free version. Even compiler is not free and that practicaly eliminates Delphi as tool for open source development.

And one thing that contributed far more to that slow declining is Delphi .NET compiler, Borland and later CodeGear put much effort in that product but that was big big mistake.

Comment: Interesting, I have only been working with it for a couple of days and haven't run into any problems yet. I guess price is indeed a good reason to not use Delphi.

Comment: @Lucas: I'm glad to hear that, but a bit surprised.  I found D2005 and D2006 so buggy as to be practically unusable, to be honest. The version before D2005, (which practically no one even bought and those who did almost universally hated it), Borland had [rewritten the IDE from scratch](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html) and it took another three releases before the quality reached a tolerable level, due mostly to development resource starvation because of the company's vision problems, as I outlined in my reply.

Comment: I don't think you have the data to say "Delphi usage is definitely declining." I no longer work at Embarcadero, but I can tell you that Delphi usage (license sales is the only realistic marker that can be used) *INCREASED* after Embarcadero got Delphi. There are also some very significant improvements in recent versions, and even more exciting things come in new releases. I don't work there any more, so don't call me a shill for the company ;)

Comment: @John you are right, I don't have the exact data, but basing on a fact that many 3rd party vendors died or jumped in the .NET vagon and it's getting harder to find new Delphi developers, specially young people. Every year our Croatian user group went smaler etc. All that combined and I think that I can say that Delphi usage (ecosystem) is slowly declining from times of Delphi 7, btw. I really love Delphi and was activly use it for 15 years

Comment: I used D2006 for several years and found it tolerable - as long as I turned error insight off. With it enabled there are significant memory leaks.

Comment: It can be easy to draw a broad (and wrong) conclusion based on a small amount of anecdotal evidence.  However, according to Embarcadero, Delphi sales have increased by 15% year over year since it was acquired in 2008.  http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41532

Comment: Interestingly: D1 stable, D2 buggy, D3 stable, D4 buggy, D5 mostly stable, D6 outlandishly buggy.  I believe by D5 or D6 Anders had left the development team and went on to lead .Net development at Microsoft.

Comment: @ChrisLively, Don't forget D7. which I believe is a very stable version (compared to D1, D3, D5).

Comment: IMO The most stable and best equipped versions for Win32 development have been D7, D2007 and DXE2. For iOS/OSx development the verdict is still not in ;-), especially since the FireMonkey framework was radically chained between XE2 and XE3. There are currently dozens of regression bugs for XE3 in Quality Central, but that's not really unexpected with the major rewrites they are undertaking right now (to support more platforms) - just look at the number of {$IFDEF NextGen} compiler conditions in their code ;-)

Answer (score 11):

I have used Delphi since Version 1, and introduced it to my workplace. At the time, we were using Visual Basic 3 for most of our Windows development, and I found that Delphi was head and shoulders above VB 3 for our needs.

When it came time to move from 16 to 32-bits, our development team took the opportunity to change the architecture of our product and separate the UI from the calculation engine. It was at this time that we switched from VB to 100% Delphi.

What has caused Delphi's decline over time? I think that many of the posts have covered several of the facets involved: Borland ne' Inprise ne' Borland's loss of focus on their core supporters. Later on, it was widely known that Borland was attempting to sell Delphi to an outside company, which never inspires confidence in your users.

After CodeGear acquired it, I think that the lack of a 64-bit compiler may have hampered it's adoption. I eventually gave up waiting on a 64-bit version of the compiler from CodeGear, and ported our company's calculation engine to the Free Pascal Compiler (FPC) so that we now support the 64-bit Windows as well as 32/64-bit Linux platforms.

I am really looking forward to the upcoming Delphi XE2. With support for 64-bit Windows AND OSX and iOS platforms (iOS support is due to FPC), it is the first Delphi release I have been excited about in quite some time.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is still widely used. Perhaps not as much as it once was, but I think you won't here CodeGear/Embarcadero complaining too much about their user base, which is steadily growing again. Also, Embarcadero wouldn't be switching the development of many of their (database) tools to Delphi if they thought that Delphi didn't have a future.

Answer (score 3):

One could certainly get the impression that Delphi is not doing well if one is seeking employment as a developer and has Delphi experience.  There seem to be few jobs advertised for Delphi developers, whereas there are many advertised for things like C#, Java and PHP.

Therefore it can seem to be "not a good investment" professionally to develop Delphi skills. If enough developers decide this, then it seems reasonable to conclude that there will be fewer and fewer developers embracing the tool.

Comment: If the main concern is building a resume, then there are certainly better languages to focus on. *But*, not everybody is an employee. If you own the company, or are contractor, or are in a place where you can select technology, Delphi still makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: As an owner I can't afford to spend months finding a new dev.  C# and Java already have a large talent pool to work from and make locating a new dev pretty easy.  Delphi? well, the last major Delphi shop I knew of in this area closed about 8 years ago.

Comment: I dont know where this assumption comes from that programmers cant learn new languages.  Hire a good *developer*, regardless of the particular syntax they know, and tell them to use Delphi (assuming thats what you want to use).  Smart and Gets Things Done, remember?  Learning the language is the trivial part.

Comment: @GrandmasterB - If a programmer cannot learn a new language then they are useless as a programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Been making my living with delphi since release 1.0. Now using XE with great pleasure. The Delphi market in the USA has clearly gone virtually extinct due to all the reasons mentioned. But my impression is that it is still quite healthy and popular in Europe.

I think that's because Pascal is a language created in Europe and has stronger roots and tradition there than in the USA, the birthplace of C/C++, Microsoft  and Windows, whose 'native language' is C/C++. MS and the C language family has always dominated in the world of professional Windows programming, paticularly in the USA.

Having said that, there appears to be a bit of a Delphi resurrgence lately thanks to CodeGear-Embarcadero.

Answer (score 3):

One aspect that a lot people have either ignored or somehow missed: Delphi failed to stay relevant.

When D1 came out in ('94?) there were only two development choices: Desktop or Server.  By D4 companies were basically testing the waters with Internet development.  By D7, a new application was more likely to be run in a browser than on the desktop.

Unfortunately, Delphi didn't change.  Around this time most compiler companies started failing.  Corporate was moving to the web and embracing those languages.

To be sure, there were new Desktop applications being built, but quite frankly the mainstream had moved on.

Yes, Borland screwed up, royally, but the main problem was that they didn't embrace the web.  .Net and Java did and won the hearts and minds of the vast majority of the development staff.  Even Delphi.Net was a miserable failure.  Either too little too late or simply bad execution, I'm not sure.

Unless Embarcadero changes direction, Delphi will continue to be a Desktop only product and it's *potential* market share will continue to shrink.  I understand that they have increased sales, but increasing sales in a shrinking marketplace isn't exactly where they need to be.  I suspect a lot of those sales are simply coming from companies switching away from other failures in that space.

I loved Delphi.  However, I, like many others, outgrew it over 10 years ago.  If we're lucky it will grow up too.

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft killed them**

But they had good help from themselves, they tended to have a lot of cool projects running internally but few that made it to any commercial success.

EDIT: Oh, sorry, you meant **Delphi**, not Borland. Nevermind then but it's kinda the same reason. I agree that Delphi was (is) a good IDE and in it's days superior to Visual Basic but Microsoft has too much clout to attract developers. That coupled with internal problems and the .Net switch-over together with the fact that desktop apps got less popular doomed them to obscurity

Comment: I don't really see how MS did that, if only Borland continued to work on Delphi 7 IDE and made language modernization on that code instead of chasing .NET ...

Comment: Borland also turned away from the user base that put them where they were in the 80s by hiking their prices quite a bit.  They should have stuck to the "lower end" and left high-end stuff to MS and *maybe* they'd still be talked about today.  Sad. I was a heavy user of Borland products from the mid-80s to the early 90s.

Comment: MS bought [Anders Hejlsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg), that's why. ;-)

Comment: Borland has never made DB programming easy. Their very latest product says it supports Firebird. However, you have to purchase the more expensive versions... the professional version does not come with the DBExpress drive for Firebird. What a rip off.

Comment: @Cape Cod Gunny: There's a free DBExpress driver for Firebird available from http://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/ and in my experience it's even a little bit higher-quality than the official driver.

Comment: @Mason - I know. However, it does not work when run from within the IDE. This makes testing a real pain doesn't it?

Comment: @Cape Cod Gunny: What exactly do you mean? I've used that driver for a few different projects and never had any trouble whatsoever with running them under the IDE to debug them.  Or do you mean connecting to a DB from within the Form Designer itself? AFAIK this is simply a piece of functionality that's not available in the lower-end SKUs with **any** driver.  (I might be wrong, though.)

Comment: Nah, I dont think MS had much to do with it.  Borland put themselves out of business by completely turning their backs on the smaller ISV's that made them successful in their search for big corporate money.

Answer (score 2):

Borland killed Delphi.

Writing an app using a version of Delphi a couple versions back just couldn't work.  Nothing worked.  Something simple like an FTP client, couldn't stay working.  Even simple Win API programming which work perfectly in VB6 and .NET, Delphi will work 15% of the time with the same code.  Borland only offered one Service Pack, leaving several bugs behind that they knew about.  If you want them fixed, you had no choice but to upgrade.  Judging from the users, the new version was littered with bugs, IDE crashes, and non-sense from Borland saying, "We have to keep ourselves profitable", implying that we have to keep paying them for the new versions which come out every year, otherwise they provide no support or fixes.

I was rooting for Delphi.  As a VB6 user I had to make a decision if I should switch to .NET, or Borland Delphi or C++.  The answer was clear, since Borland didn't care, then .NET.  Other users dropped Delphi and moved to .NET.  Even now, the thought of going to the new version of Delphi just makes me feel sick.  Memories how it just kept failing and nothing worked and Borland's greed, just make me want to stay away and not waste my time.  It's sad to see something go good, go so wrong.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, Borland is gone and Delphi is under new management now, run by folks who actually care about product quality.  You ought to give it another look.  The recent releases are light-years better than the bad days.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi is still alive and kicking, it is a great tool and the latest XE2 version brought many features such as 64bit compilation, iOS and MACOS compilation. So it is now a trully NATIVE Multi-Platform development tool.

It is really sad what Borland did to Delphi but Embarcadero seems to be changing the game, I use Delphi since version 4 and I´m currently on XE2, and this is by far the best version of Delphi ever released and since it is now multi-platform I would expect newer versions of Delphi to support Win32, Win64, MACOS, iOS, Android, Linux... all major platforms in the market.

The productivity of Delphi is incredible, and as a company owner I would never change our development platform, even if it is harder to find Delphi developers now, learning the language is really fast for a skilled DEVELOPER. In 2011 we hired 3 developers that didn´t know Delphi and now they have a very solid knowledge of the language and are producing many things really fast

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Delphi since about version 3.  Since version 8 (which can't really count as a product as it was so terrible), each successive version of Delphi was an improvement on the last.  Delphi as improved greatly under Embarcadero, and I'm looking forward to future innovations.

The whole divestment Borland made from Delphi was totally insane (at least from my perspective looking in), and unsurprisingly they were purchased by MicroFocus - a company whose claim to fame was Cobol for .Net.

But it's good to know that Delphi is now in Embarcadero's capable hands.

Comment: Delphi 4 and 6 were stumbles, that 5 and 7 fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi is alive as mentioned above not only because now it is owned by a company who cares, but also because there is a oss project fpc/Lazarus. It is inspired by Turbo Pascal/Delphi and has a very high level of compatibility with Delphi. Moreover, the current Delphi version uses fpc to compile for iOS target. This means that Embarcadero doesn't see this project as a threat, but rather as a partner.

Answer (score 0):

I started programming with delphi and interbase back in 1997. Delphi was the best programming tool. i remembered when the 3 layers concept came around, it made database applications much more easy and powerful. Until Delphi 7, the IDE was perfect. But when Delhpi 8 was released it changed a lot. They made everything different, the entire UI was modified and it was suppose to be the .NET version, the VCL components got hard to find and the entire IDE became much more heavier to run in those "back in the days" brand new MS XP SP1 installed running in low performance hardware. So basicly thats when the declined started. Deciding between my delhi 7 and any new version of Borland Delphi, I stick with Delphi 7. So not only for me but for a lot of other programmers that I know that worked with Delphi share this same point of view. Also delphi 7 was very easy to crack. we just hat to install and the serial number was all number "1".

From 2007 until now I've been working with PHP5 so I dont know how is the Embarcadero's version.

good luck